# Align overflow text and icon inside table cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I created a sortable HTML column table as follows:

```css
.dashed-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 48px; 
}

table.table-generic {
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 1100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.table-generic tr {
  
}

.table-generic tr.first-row {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #D1D1D1;
  cursor: default;
}

.table-generic tr.first-row:hover {
  background: #fff; 
}

.table-generic td, th {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.table-generic tr.selectable-row:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1; 
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.table-generic th {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.alternate-bg {
  background-color: #f8f8f8; 
}

.selected-bg,
.selected-bg:hover {
  background-color: #D0F3FF !important;
  outline: solid 1px #fff !important;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.table-generic td.icon {
  text-align: center; 
  padding-left: 0;
}

i {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon i:hover {
  color: #00c983;
}

.table-sort i {
  margin-left: 8px;
  display: inline;
}

.money {
  text-align: right !important; 
}

.history a {
  color: #0099ff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

button {
  height: 32px;
  width: 48px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

button i {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px !important;
}

.green {
  background-color: #00c983;
}

.red {
  background-color: #FF7979;
}

.table-action {
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  text-align: center;
}

th.table-action .checkbox {
  transform: translateX(-6px); 
}

.table-action input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: solid 1px #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border 0.4s;
}

.checkbox-checked {
  border: solid 1px #00c983;
  margin-top: 2px;
  transition: border 0.4s;
}

.checkbox-input {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox i {
  color: #00c983;
  display: none;
}

.checkbox i:hover {
  color: #00c983;
}

.table-generic th:first-child,
.table-generic td:first-child {
  padding-left: 24px;
}

#table1 th:first-child,
#table1 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.table-generic td:last-child {
  padding-right: 24px;
}

.table-action-last {
  padding-right: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

th.table-action-last {
  cursor: default;
}

.table-sort {
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.table-pagination {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.table-pagination-btn i {
  color: #333; 
}

.table-pagination-btn {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  height: 38px;
  border: solid 1px #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.table-pagination-btn-each {
  line-height: 38px; 
  width: 38px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: solid 1px #D1D1D1;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-pagination-btn-each:first-child {
  border-left: transparent; 
}

.table-pagination-btn-each:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8; 
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.table-pagination-btn-each i {
  font-size: 8px; 
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.table-pagination-btn-each.selected-page {
  background-color: #00c983;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.pagination-disabled,
.pagination-disabled:hover {
  cursor: default;
  color: #aaa;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.pagination-disabled i {
  cursor: default;
  color: #aaa;
}

.table-generic td .yes-no {
  color: #333; 
  cursor: default;
}

.table-generic td .fa-minus {
  font-size: 8px; 
}

.yes-no-cell {
  text-align: center !important;
  padding-right: 32px !important;
  color: transparent;
}

.table-generic td .input-text {
  height: 30px; 
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 118px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-amount {
  text-align: right; 
  padding-right: 28px !important;
}

.input-amount-row {
  position: relative;
}

.spinner-table {
  top: 50% !important;
  right: 12px !important;
  transform: translateY(-50%) !important;
}

.table-view-link {
  color: #0099ff; 
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.table-view-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.spinner-up i,
.spinner-down i {
  color: #777;
}

.spinner-up i:hover,
.spinner-down i:hover {
  color: #00c983;
}

.spinner-down i {
  transform: translateY(-1px); 
}

a:hover {
  color: #006BB3;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.table-caption {
  margin-top: 24px; 
}

td .fa-check {
  margin-left: 1.5px; 
}

#table2 td {
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

.table-generic-btn-container {
  white-space: nowrap !important; 
}

.table-generic-btn-container .table-btn {
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="dashed-wrapper">

<table class="table-generic" id="table1" data-shrinked="0" data-expanded="0">
  <tr class="first-row">
    <th class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></th>
    <th class="table-action table-action-last">Edit</th>
    <th class="table-sort" id="req-no">Request No.<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th class="table-sort" id="emp-id">Employee ID<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th class="table-sort" id="emp-name">Employee Name<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th>  
    <th class="table-sort" id="fam-member">For Family<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th class="table-sort" id="req-date">Request Date<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th> 
    <th>Editable Example</th> 
    <th>Total Amount</th> 
    <th>Details</th>
    <th>Approval History</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/TRA/04/005</td> 
    <td>EMP004</td>
    <td class="overflow-content">I Putu Yudi Haryasa</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>04 May 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">300,000.00</td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/MED/04/004</td>
    <td>EMP005</td>
    <td class="overflow-content">Daniel Giovanni Gunawan</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>04 May 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">550,000.00</td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/MED/04/003</td> 
    <td>EMP006</td>
    <td class="overflow-content">Muhammad Nadzeri Munawar</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">1<i class="fas fa-check yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>03 May 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">4,500,000.00</td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/MED/03/002</td> 
    <td>EMP007</td>
    <td class="overflow-content">Glenn Kristanto</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">1<i class="fas fa-check yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>02 May 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">3,000,000.00</td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/TRA/03/001</td> 
    <td>EMP008</td>
    <td class="overflow-content">Hendryanto Fudiko</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>02 May 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">150,000.00</td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/TRA/02/001</td> 
    <td>EMP004</td>
    <td class="overflow-content">I Putu Yudi Haryasa</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>28 Apr 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">300,000.00</td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/MED/01/005</td>
    <td>EMP021</td>
    <td class="overflow-content">Daniel Widjaja</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>25 Apr 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">550,000.00</td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/MED/01/004</td> 
    <td>EMP020</td>
    <td class="overflow-content">Faris Kurniawan</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">1<i class="fas fa-check yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>25 Apr 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">4,500,000.00</td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/ENT/01/002</td> 
    <td>EMP015</td>
    <td class="overflow-content">Romy Kusuma</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">1<i class="fas fa-check yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>11 Apr 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">3,000,000.00</td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable-row">
    <td class="table-action checkbox-action"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" checked><span class="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></td>
    <td class="icon table-action table-action-last"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
    <td>REI/ENT/01/001</td> 
    <td>EMP006</td>
    <td class="overflow-content">Muhammad Nadzeri Munawar</td>
    <td class="yes-no-cell">0<i class="fas fa-minus yes-no"></i></td>
    <td>09 Apr 2018</td>
    <td class="input-amount-row">
      <input class="input-amount input-text input-with-spinner money-input" type="text" value="0.00">
      <a />
      <div class="spinner-group amount-spinner-group spinner-table">
        <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
        <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="money">150,000.00</td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See details</a></td>
    <td class="table-generic-btn-container"><a class="button white-btn table-btn">See approvals</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, the title row icons automatically in-line aligned like this:

[image]

Is there any way to place the sort icon like this? So the text still can be overflow vertically, but the icon stay in place centered vertically directly beside the text? I tried to place the text and the icon in inline-block, but then the icon will move below the text. I also tried placing the icon absolute toward the text but I'm not really sure how to do that while maintaining the size of my title cells.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you want more stylistic freedom you may have to use something other than tables. Tables, by nature are restrictive in their ability to be styled.

The only way I can see to make this work is *super* hacky and not recommended. There's no quick fix. You'll have to use CSS to style position each icon. You'll need to add a specific class to each . I added the class `id`

```
<th class="table-sort id" id="emp-id">Employee ID<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th>
```

Then you can add a specific style for that icon:

```
.table-sort.id i {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

You'll have to do this for every icon though so depending on how many tables you have this may or may not be a viable option.

[Working fiddle here (only on the above mentioned element)](https://jsfiddle.net/jarrodwhitley/utcr098m/)